# PHP secure hash generator

Tags: php, security

As I understand it, blowfish (actually eksblowfish, as it's used one way) is generally seen a secure hashing algorithm, even for enterprise use (correct me if I'm wrong). Because of this, I created functions to create and check secure password hashes using this algorithm, and using the (also deemed cryptographically secure) openssl_random_pseudo_bytes function to generate the salt.

```
<?php
/*
 * Generate a secure hash for a given password. The cost is passed
 * to the blowfish algorithm. Check the PHP manual page for crypt to
 * find more information about this setting. Returns null on failure.
 */
function generate_hash($password, $cost=11){
    /* To generate the salt, first generate enough random bytes. Because
     * base64 returns one character for each 6 bits, the we should generate
     * at least 22*6/8=16.5 bytes, so we generate 17. Then we get the first
     * 22 base64 characters
     */
    $salt=substr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(17,$secure)),0,22);
    /* If the random generation was not secure enough, do not continue
     */
    if(!$secure) return null;
    /* As blowfish takes a salt with the alphabet ./A-Za-z0-9 we have to
     * replace any '+' in the base64 string with '.'. We don't have to do
     * anything about the '=', as this only occurs when the b64 string is
     * padded, which is always after the first 22 characters.
     */
    $salt=str_replace("+",".",$salt);
    /* Next, create a string that will be passed to crypt, containing all
     * of the settings, separated by dollar signs
     */
    $param='$'.implode('$',array(
            "2y", //select the most secure version of blowfish (>=PHP 5.3.7)
            str_pad($cost,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT), //add the cost in two digits
            $salt //add the salt
    ));

    /* Now do the actual hashing
     */
    $hash=crypt($password,$param);
    if(strlen($hash)!=60) return null;
    return $hash;
}

/*
 * Check the password against a hash generated by the generate_hash
 * function.
 */
function validate_pw($password, $hash){
    /* Regenerating the with an available hash as the options parameter should
     * produce the same hash if the same password is passed.
     */
    return crypt($password, $hash)===$hash;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why bother reinventing the wheel? Time and energy best spent upgrading your PHP version to 5.5, which introduced the `password_hash` function, to be called like so: `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('salt' => 'yourSalt', 'cost' => 15));`

Comment: Or even use something like phpass http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ . I feel that it is better to use something tested than roll your own (which may include vulnerabilities)

Comment: If PHP 5.5 isn't available, ircmaxell has made a drop in PHP version that just requires PHP 5.3: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Answer (score 3):

I would have to agree with @EliasVanOotegem. Consider using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. All you've done is recreate something, which [we know shouldn't be done](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why).

Documentation for the [former](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [latter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).